# Can someone tell me whats wrong with this python code?

Tags: python-2.7

Note: I'm using Python 2.7

I'm not very experienced at Python, but I decided to make a small simple program. Here is the code:

```
import random

while True:
    randomNumber = random.randrange(1, 3)
    print randomNumber
    guessedNumber = raw_input("Choose a number between 1 and 3 ")
    if randomNumber == guessedNumber:
        print 'Yay! You got it right!'
    else:
        print 'You got it wrong :( The number was:',randomNumber
#The first print is just for testing.
```

But when I try to run it I get this:
[IDLE after i used the program a few times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8oiu.png)

Can someone tell me what i need to change or what is wrong with the code?

Comment: Note: "1" != 1. In Python 2 you could use `input` rather than `raw_input` (which always returns a string).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as integers in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers-in-python)

Comment: @JohnColeman `int(raw_input())` is usually considered a better approach as it won't try to evaluate the input which gives you a chance to validate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`raw_input` returns a string to `guessedNumber`, and your program compares a string (`guessedNumber`) to an integer (`randomNumber`), so `if randomNumber == guessedNumber` never evaluates to `True`.

The solution is to convert `guessedNumber` to an `int` and then compare the two values.